# I am writing a hangman code for class, but my number filter loop does not work

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I am writing a code for class due tomorrow(sorry for the late notice) but my number filter will not loop or detect the numbers. Could someone help please, also explain thoroughly as possible cause I have to the same when i present as well.

```
tryagain = True
print("Welcome to Hangman: The Game. Made by Matt, Will and Dom")
    while tryagain:
        print("To play please have player one input a word for player two to guess")
        Input = input("Player one, Please input a word: ").lower()
        Answer = Input.lower()
        numbers = ("123456789!@#$%^&*()_+{}:<>?|/.,';\][")
        if numbers in Answer:
        print("No numbers or speicals characters please")
        continue
        game = "_" * len(Answer)
        alreadySaid = set()
        mistakes = 7
        print("Player two, Your word is", " ".join(game))
        guess = False
        while not guess and mistakes > 0:
            attempt = input("Player two, please guess a letter: ")
            if attempt in Answer:
                 alreadySaid.add(attempt)
                 game = " ".join([char if char in alreadySaid else "*" for char in Answer])
                 if game == Answer:
                     guess = True
            else:
               mistakes -= 1
               print ("Wrong letter", "You have", mistakes, "left")
               if mistakes == 0:

   print("You have lost player Two")
            break
    print(" ".join(Answer))
tryagain = (input("Again [y/n]: ").lower() == 'yes')
if tryagain == "yes":
            continue
```

Comment: Next time, add tags for the programming language your using. You can do so with this question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `numbers in Answer` will evaluate to `True` only if `Answers` contains the *entire* String `numbers`. It *doesn’t* return `True` if `Answers` only contains one or more characters in `numbers`.

A regular expression would be useful to you in this context.

Comment: oh ok, then how do i Make it singular to detect one or more

Comment: Then what would you recommend?

Comment: One way to do that is to use a regular expression. If you haven’t learned about them yet, then you will have to get creative and think of another way. (Sorry I can’t say more than that - I don’t want to do your homework for you :)

Comment: I understand but the teacher does not teach us how to code, we mainly go over the workings of a computer, he expects us to google it. If you still don't "want to do my homework for me" could you give me some more hints please

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting way to learn. Well, searching the web for answers when we're stuck is something we programmers do every day. :)  Okay, another hint. It appears to me that what you would like you code to do is detect whether or not a string is composed solely of alphabetical characters.  There is a method on the String type that does exactly this. The documentation for this type is located here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods If you search that page, you will find what you are looking for.